# How to get argument from url in flutter web using get: ^3.26.0

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-getx

```
return GetMaterialApp(
      title: title,
      theme: appTheme,
      getPages: [
        GetPage(name: '/', page: () => Splash()),
        GetPage(name: '/update', page: () => Update()),
        GetPage(name: '/login', page: () => SignIn()),
        GetPage(name: '/reference', page: () => Reference()),
      ],
      home: Splash(),
    );
```

this is my route code and now i want to user enter url like : xyz.com/login/jayesh , then i want to get user name in login screen using getx state management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add page  with name in GetMaterialApp

```
getPages:[
    GetPage(name: '/login/:refId', page: () => SignIn()),    
        ],
```

you can retrive data(perameter) like:

```
var data = Get.parameters;
String id = data['refId'];
```

Answer (score 3):

In your route:

```
xyz.com/login?username=jayesh
```

And in your controller or in your view:

```
var username = Get.parameters["username"];
```

*A good place to get your arguments or parameters may be in your controllers **onInit** or your views **build** method*

Comment: "A good place to get your arguments or parameters may be in your controllers onInit or your views build method" - if this really works no-one will ask such questions. "onInit" is called only once during lifecycle, after widget is allocated in memory; considering you use constant widgets for the best performance... never works as expected: subsequent calls to same route, even with different parameters, won't trigger neither "onInit" nor ""build" methods for different parameters. There are hundreds of SO questions regarding how to workaround this. Maybe I am mistaken, please prove.